# How to find product of arithmetic progression?

Tags: c#

I need to write a function to find a product of arithmetic progression elements (using recursion). I have only vague idea how to do it – something like this:

```
public static int product(int n)
{
   if (n == 0)
      return 0;
   else
      return <some code> * product(n-1);
}
```

Could you at least give me a hint?

Comment: @Jamiec this won't be arithmetic progression even if `<some code>` is `n`. It will be factorial in that case.

Comment: @ Jamiec: and that is it?

Comment: what is your function supposed to actually do? My first comment assumed you were just trying to multiply a sequence (like `3*2*1`)

Comment: This will always return **0** because once `n == 1` the recursive call will be `product(1 - 1)`.

Comment: What is the arithmetic progression? Can you give some samples of input and output that you expect?

Comment: Is that fixed or do you need to be able to alter those variables (ie does this need to work for that one specific sequence or for the general case where `a` and `d` are both provided?

Comment: Why does your function only take 1 parameter  then?

Comment: @ Chris: it should work for all cases like this

Comment: @ Jamiec: it takes only one parameter because I do not know how to make it recursive with multiple parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
public static int Product(int arithInitial, int arithDifference, int n)
{
   if (n == 1)
      return GetArithmeticSeriesTerm(arithInitial,arithDifference,1);
   else
      return GetArithmeticSeriesTerm(arithInitial,arithDifference,n) * Product(arithInitial, arithDifference, n-1);
}

public static int GetArithmeticSeriesTerm(int initial, int difference, int position)
{
    return initial+difference*(position-1);
}
```

I have created a new method to get the elements of the arithmetic progression. I've also changed the base case of the recursion to be n==1 and then put the call to the arithmetic series term.

It should hopefully be pretty self explanatory as to what it does.

For the first four terms of the series 1,3,5,7,... you would call it as

```
int result = Product(1,2,4)`
```

Note: You don't need two methods for this but I feel that introducing the second method makes it clearer what the code is doing. You could of course just inline the expression and of course your base case can in fact be simplified to just `initial` if you wanted to make it a bit cleaner. Using the full method though makes it very intuitive of why we are doing that.

Comment: Now it seems pretty clear for me. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a function which take 3 arguments first Term(f) , common difference(d) , and total number of term (n) in AP.

```
     int fun(int f,int d,int n){
      if(n==0) return 1;
else (f+(n-1)*d) * fun(f,d,n--);
    }
```

Comment: you use an undefined `a` variable in your method.  I think that should be f? Your variables are so horribly named its hard to be sure though. ;-)